# C++ Builder Performance

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++builder

Can anyone explain how does the latest XE5 compare to a compiler such as Visual C++ from Microsoft? Because recent versions of C++ Builder use CLang which is based on LLVM. I haven't found no documentation or articles that compares the two.

Comment: 64bit compiler is based on LLVM, 32bit not yet.

Comment: @mhtaqia Hopefully XE6 :) Because I noticed it has VC++ Compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this question is still valid, but it's not clear what you mean for "compare": performance, standard compliance..ecc

Anyway [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) you can find a table that compares C++ new features (up to C++17) between all compilers including MSVC and C++ Builder.